# Inkscape crashes no matter what I try. How do I troubleshoot

Tags: inkscape

I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask questions about inkscape crashed. (See below about why I am not asking on the inkscape.org forum).

I've upgraded my Mac with an M1 chip to Ventura. I've installed Inkscape 1.2 via a package from Inkscape.org and through macports.  Both crash after showing an initial welcome screen.  I don't know what to do next.

Does anyone have advice on what I should try?

For me at least, this is semi-urgent.

(The login on the inkscape forum appears to be broken. I've asked for a password reset on two different email accounts I have, and I have never received the reset-email. Otherwise, I wouldn't be asking there).

Comment: Tech support is off topic. But.. I installed X11 (actually needed for local PHP/MySQL), and then Inkscape on Ventura, then upgraded to Sonoma on an M2 and there were/are no issues. I don't believe I have MacPorts on the M2 system.

Comment: SIgh. I was afraid of that, but thanks for the feedback.  Wish I knew where to turn to. If anyone out there knows of a place to make inquiries,  a note in the comment section here would be very much appreciation.

Comment: Would using Inkscape 1.3 be an option?

Comment: https://inkscape.org/contribute/report-bugs/